# cutting sound actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to make an application to cut a sound from a file(mp3) with flash actionscript 3, let just say i have music.mp3 with 2 minutes length, and i want to save it as a new file (with save dialog), but with different length, (for example, only from second 30 to 60).

is that possible? if yes, how?

here's my code so far:

```
var s:Sound = new MySound() as Sound;
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
/*
s.extract maybe? then?
*/
```

thank you